# Accessing Cload Firestore Database using a locally running Firebase Function Emulator

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, emulation

I use the Firebase Emulator Suite to run and debug my Cload Functions locally, as described in this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

I got a Cload Firestore Database ready-to-go with some data in it.

I try to fetch data from Cload Firestore through my locally emulated cload functions.

My approach so far was following the "Writing the Cloud Function Code" section in https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-firestore

My functions/src/index.ts file looks like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const PROJECTID = 'XYZ';
const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: PROJECTID
});

const logger = function(object: any){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
} 

export const create_order = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        // var test_doc_id = "82GKB2P6xee9lftOidDj";
        const trucks = firestore.collection("trucks").get();
        logger(trucks);
        response.send(JSON.stringify(firestore));
    });
});
```

I expected the value of "trucks" to be an array of all trucks coming from firestore, but there is no result "{}" coming back.

Can someone give me hints, guides and suggestions how to do this in a correct way ?

Best regards, and thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

`firestore.collection("trucks").get()` [returns a Promise](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data).

If you want to log out the data, you could write an asynchronous method:

```
cors(request, response, async () => {
  const trucks = await firestore.collection('trucks').get();
  logger(trucks);
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can control which DB functions are listening to with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. Running without will listen to local, while running with your production `firebaseAdminSdkServiceAccount.json` will listen to changes on production DB.

On windows you would start it from terminal like this:

```
SET GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/config/firebaseAdminSdkServiceAccount.json
firebase emulators:start
```

Then for listening for firestore document changes you reference:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
functions.firestore.document('/mydoc/{mydocId}').onWrite(...)
```

EDIT: To make sure I'm right I did some googling, and came up with this explaination:

> When using emulators:start we want to keep people inside the local
>   emulation environment unless they specifically ask to be broken out.
>   Right now, you can ask to contact production by manually restoring the
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL files when running in the emulator.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1412#issuecomment-504561828